# N2 CMS - My Items dont show in the tree

Tags: content-management-system, n2

Anyone familier with N2 CMS ??

ive just started using it, and so far so good, but i have an issue that im sure you guys will know whats wrong.

i have this simple Item class...

```
using N2;
using N2.Details;
using MVCSite.ContentCMSItems;

[PageDefinition("Home page", Description = "The Page for the home page")]
[WithEditableName]
public class PageItem : AbstractBaseClass
{
/// <summary>
/// There are code snippets to help generate these properties.
/// Look in the snippets directory of the package.
/// </summary>
[EditableFreeTextArea("MainText", 97)]
public virtual string MainText
{
    get { return (string)GetDetail("MainText"); }
    set { SetDetail("MainText", value); }
}

    [EditableFreeTextArea("Home Page Fotter Text", 100)]
    public virtual string FooterText
    {
        get { return (string)GetDetail("Home Page Fotter Text"); }
        set { SetDetail("Home Page Fotter Text", value); }
    }
}
```

In edit mode, N2 CMS picks it up and i can create a page and fill in all the data.

Once this is done i expect to see it in the tree, below my start page, but it never shows.

All the data is in the database but not in the tree, so once its created i cannot edit it :(

can anyone suggest what im doing wrong ??

thanks for your time

Truegilly

Comment: The third using statement - for the purposes of example code, I might have changed that myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, as i copied the AbstractBaseClass which it inherits, from the N2CMS MVC example project, it contained methods that caused this problem. After removing these it now shows in the tree.

Truegilly